# How to I take an array and put it into another array to make a multi-dimensional array in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, multidimensional-array

I want to make an array, then push arrays onto the array as elements. How do I do that?

```js
let array3 = [];

const array1 = [1,2];
const array2 = [3,4];

array3.push(array1);
console.log(array3);
// expected [[1,2]]

array3.push(array2);
console.log(array3);
// expected [[1,2],[3,4]]
```

This what I am trying to make work:

```js
const _ = {
  chunk: (array, chunkSize = 1) =>{
console.log(`Original Array: ${array}` );
let chunk = [];
let chunkArr = [];
while(array.length > 0)
{
  while(chunk.length < chunkSize && array.length > 0)
  {
    chunk.push(array.shift());
  }
  console.log(`Chunk: ${chunk}`);

  chunkArr.push(chunk);

  console.log(`Chunk Array: ${chunkArr}` );

  while(chunk.length > 0)
  {
    chunk.pop();
  }
}
//console.log(`chunk array: ${chunkArr}` );
return chunkArr;
  }

// end of _ object
};

const array = [1,2,3,4];
console.log(_.chunk(array, 2));
```

Comment: Your output matches your expected. What's the problem?

Comment: That is what you are doing, do you want to merge them?

Comment: Ok, this is even more frustrating that the sample I provided works but not the code I am using that appears to be the same...

Comment: you mean you want the array [1,2,3,4] --> [[1,2], [3,4]] ?

Comment: Yes, but with the function and being able to take arrays of any length and divide them into small arrays and save that into a larger array. Moreso, I just wanted to know why my function wasn't working and thought the problem was pushing arrays together, because in my function it isn't working as I expect.

Comment: change chunkArr.push(chunk) --> chunkArr.push([...chunk]) it works, because you had changed chunk after chunkArr pushed chunk, and its an array, not a primitives data type

Comment: So the chunkArr was just referencing the chunk variable from the array instead of copying the values? So if I had changed the values in chuckArr that would change the values in chuck also?

Comment: yes, it's true, so my suggestion is to use constants instead of variables and don't use the methods with side effects as possible as you can

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
const array1 = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8];
const chunk = (arr, size = 2, sum = []) => {
  if (arr.length <= size) {
   return sum.concat([arr])
  }
  return chunk(arr.slice(size), size, sum.concat([arr.slice(0, size)]));
}
console.log(chunk(array1, 5))
```

Comment: This is great, exactly what I wanted to do. I am just wondering what is wrong with mine.